Meaning difference between "somebody be seen to do" and its active counterpart

i They had seen him drive, so everyone decided to go by bus.
ii He had been seen to drive, so everyone decided to go by bus.


Notice that [i] is perfectly coherent, but [ii] is not. In [i] they had perceived the event, and hence the manner of his driving, and we infer that it was the latter that made them decide to go by bus. But in [ii] it is
the fact of his driving that had been registered, and this doesn’t provide an obvious reason for them to go by bus.

( All of the above is from CGEL, P.1237)
And the writer suggests in an earlier part that "ii" has at least a trace of the cognitive component of meaning. ( I'm not sure if it is useful information)
I would like somebody explain further the exact meaning of "ii", because what I have learned and always thought is that "ii" is precisely the  passive counterpart of "i": there is no difference in meaning.
Does the book mean: in "ii", we didn't  see the whole process of his driving--what was seen and maybe subsequently inferred was only that he can drive. (just guessing).

Take care with CGEL examples.  It isn't interested (much) in normal language, but in the "edge cases".  Lots of the examples are on the very edges of English grammar, and so aren't good for understanding typical English.  I think CGEL explains this very well and I wouldn't know what else can be said.

If CGEL says the sentence is not coherent, why are you asking about it here? Do you know what "coherent" means?

The problem is that this is not even about grammar. To be seen to do something or be doing something is completely idiomatic in English. And that resultative clause may make sense in certain contexts, like a police investigation.

They had seen him drive. Compare: He had been seen to drive by them. The discussion by CGEL should be taken with a grain of salt. The discussion about ii) is about logic, not grammar.

@Stuartf  I know coherent, but  I was hoping someone could analyze the meaning of the second sentence， maybe from a different angle, so that I can understand why it is not coherent.

The two constructions carry significantly different implications.
#1 implies the way he was seen to drive affected people's willingness to be chauffeured by him (almost certainly, because he drove badly / dangerously).
#2 is totally non-idiomatic as presented, because the initial clause simply implies people know he drives (because they've seen him driving). It implies nothing about how well or badly he drives - it just emphasizes that he does (and hence obviously can) drive. It's only normally used in contexts where it's expected the subject doesn't / can't / shouldn't do something. Here's a more natural context for the second construction...

John was banned from driving for life, because he suffers from epileptic fits.
But he has been seen to drive, which is dangerous for both him and others.


Note that in almost all contexts, all of these forms mean exactly the same thing, but the first version (with known rather than seen) is far more common...

A: He has been known to do it
B: He has been seen to do it
C: He has been seen doing it


The grammar and logic of sentences are not the same thing. There could be all sorts of context not given in the example: He had given up driving but had been seen to drive, so everyone decided to go by bus. I think the CGEL example is bad news. Everyone is agreeing with you so it looks like past perfect is never on, but it could be.

My answer
Personally I disagree with the commentary on the two sentences. They are both coherent, and mean broadly the same thing.
The detail


They had seen him drive, so everyone decided to go by bus.
He had been seen to drive, so everyone decided to go by bus.


Grammatically we have two clauses. The first clause describes people seeing him drive. The second clause describes their decision to take the bus. The conjunction so (=therefore) tells us that the second clause is an action inspired by the first clause. The only significant grammatical difference is that in sentence #1, the first clause is in the active voice, but in sentence #2 it is in the passive voice.
According to CGEL:

In [i] they had perceived the event, and hence the manner of his driving, and we infer that it was the latter that made them decide to go by bus. But in [ii] it is the fact of his driving that had been registered, and this doesn’t provide an obvious reason for them to go by bus.

But to me this seems to be a very arbitrary distinction. In sentence 1 "they saw him drive" and in sentence 2 "he had been seen to drive". The essence of this is a person driving, and people observing that fact. The only possible difference is that in sentence #2 the passive voice (he was seen...) means we don't know who saw him. Theoretically it could have been other bystanders, who then spoke to "everyone". But technically the same ambiguity exists in the first sentence as well. They and everyone presumably describe the same set of people, but that is an interpretation.
But the most important point here is that the first clause in both sentences tells us nothing about the man's driving. It's only the addition of the second clause that alerts us to a problem. GCEL itself admits this when it says we can infer that the manner of his driving caused them to go by bus. It's a deduction we have to make. Maybe he appeared to be drunk. Maybe he was speeding. Maybe he looked like a foreigner who didn't know the local road rules. None of this matters, because the fact is, we are not told. We are simply told by the grammatical connection that there is a plausible factual link between the two clauses. And we are reasonably invited to make exactly the same inference in the second sentence.

Personally I disagree with this answer. The two sentences don't mean broadly the same thing. The first one strongly implies that the way he drove was in some way "unusual" (probably because he drove unsafely). The second one is only normally used to refute prior assertions that he can't / doesn't / shouldn't drive - it implies nothing about the way he drove, simply that he did drive.

To me they don't mean the same thing. The first contains an implication about how he drives. The second merely contains the fact that he drives. With no implication about the quality of his driving, it makes less sense

@FumbleFingers, I take your point that sentence #2 (for example) could be interpreted as They saw him leave/saw that he had left, so they took the bus as the only other transport option. (ie, no criticism of his driving.) But I would argue that if we only had sentence #1, we could interpret that the same way. My main point is that I don't see either sentence as incoherent. Both require interpretation. Both can be reasonably interpreted. And without context, that's about all we have.

I can't agree that OP's example #2 could be interpreted as They saw him leave/saw that he had left, so... If you want  drive to mean leave, depart you absolutely require a suitable preposition - drive away, drive off,...

My first thought when reading the question was that ‘he’ was the bus driver, and they all decided to take the bus because they liked him and wanted him to be their driver, so I find the inference quite vague in the first sentence; but in the second version, there’s just no inference at all. The fact that he had been observed driving (by someone) does not invite any inference as to why ‘everyone’ (whoever exactly that is) would take the bus. The examples in TimR’s answer are even clearer: “I wouldn’t hire him to paint my house – he’s been seen painting!” is completely meaningless.

They didn't trust his driving.  And therefore: He had been seen to drive, so everyone decided to go by bus.

I think this is all a tempest in a teapot. Picking utterances out of the air (like CGEL has done) without context is foolhardy. Who does that? And then go on and on about them. What a waste of time. The issues are not grammar; the issues are about logic.

They had seen him drive has the practical meaning "They were quite familiar with his driving".
He had been seen to drive might mean no more than "People had a brief glimpse of him behind the wheel of an automobile".
Thus, the first could be used to explain why those who knew how he drives preferred the bus over being his passenger.  The second implies no knowledge of how good or bad a driver he is.
Compare:

I wouldn't hire him to paint my house. I have seen him paint.
I wouldn't hire him to paint my house. He has been seen to paint. oddly incongruous

In the first, "seen" is synonymous with "watched, observed closely".  In the second, "seen" is synonymous with "noticed", and so the two sentences seem unrelated.
To "notice" something is to be aware of its mere existence. To "watch" something is to become more deeply acquainted with it than awareness of its mere existence.

I drove by the Johnson's  house and noticed they were getting a new roof.
I was walking by the Johnson's house and watched the roofers. They're not a bunch of misfits but worked together like professionals.


I don't understand your point in the second sentnce with the hiring. Your second one just does not make sense even if it means noticed.

@Lambie  I think that's why he says "I wouldn't hire him to paint my house" and " He has been seen to paint"  are not related.

@Lambie:  As I said  below that example, "the two sentences seem unrelated". I've added an "oddly incongruous" superscript as an additional road-sign.

@ForOU And they are not like the OP's examples either. The fact TImR's sentence are unrelated does not explain the examples from CGEL.

@Lambie They are quite alike.  I have simply reversed the order of the clauses.  That is not a material difference.

For whatever reason, we’d say “He had been known to drive,” (the connotation is that he drives occasionally) but “He had been seen driving” (on at least one specific occasion). The phrase “been seen to drive” is not idiomatic in American English. A Google Ngrams search found that either of the two alternatives I gave were a dozen times as common as “been seen to drive,” and several of the hits for that are false positives.
I don’t know the nationality of the author or whether that wording is more common in British English.  It’s possible that, in context, the author had a reason to choose a unusual construction as an example.  Here, the nuance seems to be that “He had been seen to” do something doesn’t imply anything about how he does it, so “He had been seen to drive” doesn’t work as a reason for people do avoid letting him drive them somewhere.

Geoff Pullum is British–American, and Rodney Huddleston is British. But I don’t find ‘has been seen to do’ idiomatic in BrE either. Perfectly understandable, but not idiomatic.

Well that's the point, isn't it? The second example is deliberately off. "He had been seen to..." is not an uncommon construction, but the authors are pointing out that it doesn't work in this context.

He had been seen to drive down the street, if you believe the neighbors.  It  is idiomatic.

@Lambie Google cannot find one single page on the Web with the exact phrase "had been seen to drive down the street" or "has been seen to drive down the street", in quotes. It does find results for both "has been seen driving down the street" and "has been known to drive down the street".

Google can't prove anything. But if it is there in the present perfect, the past perfect would be grammatical. They had been seen to drive/driving down the street prior to the inquiry.

@JanusBahsJacquet "has been seen to [infinitive] is completely idiomatic in any English. Ludwig guru: 'She smiles now and has been seen to laugh. The Guardian The Crab has been seen to pulse in almost every wavelength, in radio, optical, X-rays, and gamma-rays. Harvard University One was Eubacterium dolichum, which has been seen to increase in unhealthy Western diets. The Independent

@Lambie The question is not whether it’s “grammatical” or meaningful, but whether it’s idiomatic. That is, is it something native speakers would actually say?

Of course it is. I just gave you two examples from authoritative sources.

And, past tense for the one from The Guardian: She smiled then and had been seen to laugh.

@Lambie You found examples that take other verbs. Unfortunately, English usage is not so logical.

X had been seen to do just about anything. The fact you say it is unidiomatic is shocking to me. "had been seen to x"  can take any active verb. Even more so when you say it is unidiomatic in AmE.

@Lambie It’s grammatical but uncommon, and several commenters have remarked it sounds strange to native speakers.

Well. I am a native speaker and it sounds fine to me. CGEL would not give an unidiomatic sentence. Their commentary is about the two clauses together, not one or the other...
